# Cors Not working even when configuring in webapi config

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a web api in visual studio and i also configured EnableCorsAttribute with attributes (origins:"*",headers: "*",methods: "*"). Now when i am accessing the method of controller from url i am still getting this message "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApplication1.Models.Customer]" 

Error message is as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvyGF.png

Comment: Post the complete error message. At first glance, it doesn't looks like a CORS issue

Comment: Error msg is as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvyGF.png

Comment: Kindly post your WebApiConfig.cs code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved, it was silly mistake. I was trying to access the plain controller  other than api controller to call it. I corrected it and now i am able to access and fetch the data.

Thank you all for comments and effort.

Answer (score 0):

To configure CORS in ASP.net Core 2.0 (similar in 1.*) you have to do the folowing:

In both cases below place the code before services.AddMvc() and app.UseMvc().

In your startup.cs in ConfigureServices method:

```
        if (environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            services.AddCors();
        }
        services.AddMvc();
```

in Configure method:

```
        if (environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseCors(
                options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()
            );
        }
        app.UseMvc();
```

You can skip if statements if you want this behavior in production too.

Remember to reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors package.

Comment: i dont find any  ConfigureServices  method in startup.cs, is it necessary to create it and call services.AddCors(); in it.

Comment: Are you using ASP.net core ore ASP.net webapi 2 ? My answer is acctually for ASP.net core projectes

Comment: I have been using ASP.net webapi 2